# Homomorphism between polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, integral-domain

> Let $A$ be an integral domain, and $c\in A$. Let $h:A[x]\rightarrow A[x]$ be defined by $h(a(x))=a(cx)$, that is, $$h(a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n)=a_0+a_1cx+\ldots+a_nc^nx^n.$$ Prove that $h$ is a homomorphism and describe its kernel. Prove that $h$ is an automorphism if and only if $c$ is invertible.

To show that $h$ is a homomorphism, we note that $$h(a(x)+b(x))=(a+b)(cx)=a(cx)+b(cx)=h(a(x))+h(b(x)).$$

Also, $$h(a(x)b(x))=(a\cdot b)(cx)=a(cx)b(cx)=h(a(x))h(b(x)).$$

$a(x)$ is in the kernel iff $a_0=a_1c=\ldots=a_nc^n=0$. (Is there an easier way to describe this?)

Now, I'm not sure what to do with the automorphism (which means checking surjectivity and injectivity).

Comment: Given $c\in A$ which is an integral domain, $c^k=0\implies c=0$ for $k>0$.  This implies the kernel of $h$ consists of only the zero element of $A[x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is an integral domain, if $a_ic^k=0$, either $a_i=0$ or $c^k=0$.

Let $r$ be the minimum power $k$ for which $c^k=0$. Then we get that $a_i=0$ for $i<r$ is the condition for $a_0+a_1x+...a_nx^n$ being in the kernel.

.......

If $c$ is a unit then $g(p(x)):=p(c^{-1}x)$ is the inverse of $h$.

.......

Assume now that $h$ is invertible with inverse $g$. Then $a_0=g(h(a_0))=g(a_0)$. So, $g$ fixes coefficients (the elements of $A$). Because of this $g(ap(x))=g(a)g(p(x))=ag(p(x))$, for $a\in A$.

Also $g(h(x))=g(cx)=cg(x)=x$. Therefore $g(x)=a_nx^n...+a_1x+a_0$, with $ca_k=0$, for $k\neq1$,  and $ca_1=1$. If $c=0$ then $h(p(x))=0$, which is not invertible. Therefore $c$ is invertible with inverse $a_1$, and $a_k=0$, for $k\neq1$.

Comment: Thanks ABC. I understand that $g(a_0)=a_0$, but why does it imply $g(a_0a(x))=a_0g(a(x))$?

Comment: @Kunal Because $g$ is a homomorphism. $g(a_0a(x))=g(a_0)g(a(x))=a_0g(a(x))$.

Comment: I might be missing the obvious, but how do we know $g$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: @Kunal Yes,you are missing the obvious. The first thing you prove after defining homomorphism is that if it is invertible its inverse is a homomorphism.

Comment: Ok, I got it now, thanks.